# I am getting new error

Tags: android

[image]Error is Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.

Build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: is this your complete gradle file ?

Comment: Verify your Gradle Offline is turned off in Android Studio Preferences.

Comment: yaa I turned off my Gradle offline in Android Studio

Comment: My another Gradle file is

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Go to File->Invalidate Caches and Restart. try this.

Comment: @ParthPatel I tried this 4-5 times but of no use

Comment: Do you have import any module dependency?

Comment: @ParthPatel No I haven't import any module dependency

Comment: Then you have to create a new project and manually add all files into that. Hope it will work for you.